# Dragging img elements in IOS browsers - supress longpress menu

Tags: html, ios, draggable

I'm trying to implement drag-n-drop for moving IMG elements around on a page.
The problem on IOS browsers is when you pressing-and-hold an img element for too long it shows the longpress menu ( save image | open image in new tab | etc)

You can try this out by moving of the portrait images on the library demo site: http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/

Is there a way to supress the longpress menu? Perhaps by doing something like event.preventDefault?

Note: I cannot us background images instead of IMG elements. Cause I'm using SVG images and last time I tried IOS couldn't handle Svg background-images in all situations. So I wanna stick with IMG elements.

Comment: Drag and drop works for the images on my iPad air 2. Do you think that many people are going to start dragging then stop long enough for the long press menu to appear that's it's worth suppressing?

Comment: @beyowulf - We tested it and everyone was constantly longpressing so the menu kept popping up (I think people are used to longpressing cause that's how it works when moving stuff on the IOS homescreen)

Comment: Have you tried using svg tag?